# How can I insert an element every $n$th position in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I insert an element every $n$ positions in a list?

For example, inserting a zero as every 4th element to turn

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

into

```
{1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7}
```

Surely there must be a simpler way than

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
every = 4;
Insert[list, 0, List /@ Range[1, Floor[Length@list/(every - 1)]]*(every - 1)]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I found it curious that neither Google nor *Mathematica*'s documentation located my solution when I searched by, what were to me, the most obvious combinations of keyphrases, *e.g.* <kbd>mathematica</kbd> <kbd>insert</kbd> <kbd>every</kbd> <kbd>list</kbd>.

`Riffle` is probably an obvious thought for anyone familiar with *Mathematica*, but not a common term that newcomers could be expected to know. Until today, even my own idea of `Riffle` was that it was a "zipper" function (*i.e.* interleaving two lists but without an "every" option).

---

This is exactly one of the things `Riffle` does.

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
every = 4;
Riffle[list, 0, every]
(* {1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7} *)
```

Comment: `Insert[lst, ele, Transpose@{Range[every, Length@lst, every - 1]}]` is a bit cleaner way using `Insert`, and `Riffle` *is* in the "see also" for `Insert` (I *always* follow those links - often a surprise or an "ah-ha!" to be found there...)

Answer (score 8):

[`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html) is surely the canonical method since version 6 but there are other approaches:

```
fn1[lst_, ele_, n_, m_: 1] :=
  Take[
    Join @@ ArrayPad[Partition[lst, n, n, 1], {0, {0, m}}, ele],
    QuotientRemainder[Length @ lst, n].{n + m, 1}
  ]
```

Test:

```
fn1[Range@10, "x", 3]
fn1[Range@10, "x", 4, 2]
fn1[Range@10, "x", 5, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, "x", 4, 5, 6, "x", 7, 8, 9, "x", 10}
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4, "x", "x", 5, 6, 7, 8, "x", "x", 9, 10}
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "x", "x", "x", 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "x", "x", "x"}
> ```

Also:

```
fn1[Range@10, {"a", "b"}, 3, 2]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, "a", "b", 4, 5, 6, "a", "b", 7, 8, 9, "a", "b", 10}
> ```

Related:

- [Is there a way to riffle more than two lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58959/121)

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Fold`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = Range[10];
pos = {2, 5, 9};
Fold[Insert[#1, Style[0, Bold, Red], #2] &, list, pos]
```

[image]

---

OP's specific case:

```
everyfourthpos = Range[4, Length@list, 4]
Fold[Insert[#1, Style[0, Bold, Red], #2] &, list, everyfourthpos]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ls1 = Range[10];
ls2 = CharacterRange["a", "j"];
```

---

Positions and replacement:

```
pos = Table[{Flatten@Position[#1, #1[[k]]], {#3, 
      Extract[#1, {k}]}}, {k, #2, Length@#1, #2 - 1}] &;
```

Using `ReplacePart`:

```
rep1 = {ls1, 4, Style[0, Bold, Red]};

Flatten[ReplacePart[ls1, Thread[#[[All, 1]] -> #[[All, 2]] &@(pos @@ rep1)]]]
```

[image]

```
rep2 = {ls2, 4, Style["z", Bold, Red]};

Flatten[ReplacePart[ls2, Thread[#[[All, 1]] -> #[[All, 2]] &@(pos @@ rep2)]]]
```

[image]