# What's the foo such that foo[{a, b, c}, 2] produces {a, a, b, b, c, c}?

Tags: list-manipulation

I can define such a `foo` like this

```
foo[list_List, n_Integer] := Join @@ Transpose@ConstantArray[list, n]

foo[{3, {1, 4}, 1}, 3]
```

> ```
> {3, 3, 3, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

...but I could swear that there already is a built-in *Mathematica* function for this<sup>1</sup>.  I just can't remember it.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> ...though its signature need not be the same as `foo`'s.</sup>

Comment: [closely related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58959/106) and stealing [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58965/106) from [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods): `Flatten[{#, #, #}, {{2, 1}}] &@{3, 1, 4, 1}`

Comment: @tomd maybe `foo = Table[##] ~Flatten~ {2, 1} &`

Comment: @SimonWoods Very nice!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I cannot think of a built-in function that does this more directly than what you wrote, but for the sake of variety you can also use [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html):

```
fn[a_List, n_Integer] := PadRight[{a}, {n, Automatic}, a]\[Transpose] // Catenate

fn[{a, b, c}, 4]
```

> ```
> {a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b, c, c, c, c}
> ```

If *n* is a power of two then you could [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html) as well:

```
Nest[Riffle[#, #] &, {a, b, c}, 2]
```

> ```
> {a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b, c, c, c, c}
> ```

You could even [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) that output to get other values, though that seems rather contrived:

```
Join @@ Partition[%, 3, 4]
```

> ```
> {a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c}
> ```

### Performance

With a small change to `fn` we can eliminate the [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) operation.

```
f2[a_List, n_Integer] :=
  Catenate @ PadRight[#, {Automatic, n}, #] & @ Partition[a, 1]
```

For both light and heavy replication on packed arrays this tests faster than `foo` and remains competitive on unpacked arrays.

```
(* packed *)
foo[Range@1*^6, 5]; // RepeatedTiming
fn[Range@1*^6, 5];  // RepeatedTiming
f2[Range@1*^6, 5];  // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.3026, Null}
>
> {0.0547, Null}
>
> {0.0663, Null}
> ```

```
(* packed, heavy replication *)
foo[Range@1000, 5000]; // RepeatedTiming
fn[Range@1000, 5000];  // RepeatedTiming
f2[Range@1000, 5000];  // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.053, Null}
>
> {0.053, Null}
>
> {0.033, Null}
> ```

```
(* unpackable *)
foo[1/Range@1*^6, 5]; // RepeatedTiming
fn[1/Range@1*^6, 5];  // RepeatedTiming
f2[1/Range@1*^6, 5];  // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.351, Null}
>
> {0.4586, Null}
>
> {0.4945, Null}
> ```

```
foo[1/Range@1000, 5000]; // RepeatedTiming
fn[1/Range@1000, 5000];  // RepeatedTiming
f2[1/Range@1000, 5000];  // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0845, Null}
>
> {0.213, Null}
>
> {0.115, Null}
> ```

Answer (score 10):

```
foo[list_, n_] := Catenate @ Table[e, {e, list}, n]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use

```
f[l_List, n_Integer] := Flatten[Outer[Table, l, {n}, 1], 2]
```

or

```
ff[l_List, n_Integer] := Flatten[Thread[Table[l, n]], 1]
```

Both work:

```
f[{3, {1, 4}, 1}, 3]
ff[{3, {1, 4}, 1}, 3]
```

> `{3, 3, 3, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, 1, 1, 1}`

Answer (score 8):

In:

```
f[xs_, n_] := MapThread[Sequence, ConstantArray[xs ,n]];
f[{a,b,c}, 2]

g[xs_, n_] := Sequence @@ (Table[1, n] #) & /@ xs;
g[{a,b,c}, 2]
```

Out:

```
{a, a, b, b, c, c}
{a, a, b, b, c, c}
```

Answer (score 7):

To be readable and intuitive, I suggest:

```
repeatItems01[lst_List, n_Integer] := Catenate[ConstantArray[#, n] & /@ lst]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ff[v_List, n_Integer] := Last@Reap[Do[Sow[ConstantArray[i, n]], {i, v}]]~Flatten~2;


ff[{3, {1, 4}, 1}, 3]
(* {3, 3, 3, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

another way:

```
foo[{}, _] := {};
foo[list_, num_] := Join[ConstantArray[First@list, num], foo[Rest@list, num]];
foo[{3, {1, 4}, 1}, 3]
(* {3, 3, 3, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pretty obscure way:

```
foo[list_, n_] := ListConvolve[ConstantArray[1, n], Upsample[list, n], 1]

foo[{a, b, c, d}, 3]
{a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c, d, d, d}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
foo[k_List, reps_Integer] := 
 SequenceReplace[k, {x_} :> Sequence @@ ConstantArray[x, reps]]

list = {3, {1, 4}, 1};
foo[list, 3]
```

> {3, 3, 3, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, 1, 1, 1}

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `Sequence` and `ConstantArray`:

```
foo[l_List, n_Integer?Positive] := Sequence @@ ConstantArray[#, n] & /@ l

foo[list, 3]

(*{3, 3, 3, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, 1, 1, 1}*)
```

Or using `Subsequences` and `ReplaceAll` (with the @Syed's idea):

```
foo[l_List, n_Integer?Positive] := Subsequences[l, {1}] /. {x_} :> Sequence @@ ConstantArray[x, n]
```

Comment: Subsequences of length `1`. I will remember this usage.