# Merging two lists as a twisted comb

Tags: list-manipulation

We have two separated lists as

```
list1={{1,2},{3,5},{5,8},{18,3}};
list2={{1,1},{7,15},{10,1},{17,3}};
```

But we have to reach at

```
finallist={{1,2},{1,1},{3,5},{7,15},{5,8},{10,1},{18,3},{17,3}};
```

How we obtain the result

Comment: Riffle[list1, list2].

Comment: O my god, wonderful!!!

Comment: Or if you don't know about `Riffle`, `Flatten[Transpose[{list1, list2}], 1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built in function for that [`Riffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html)

```
Riffle[list1, list2]
```

A more general version of this question is here

> [Is there a way to riffle more than two lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58959/10397)

Where the general solutions for more than two lists are discussed

[Simon Woods'](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58965/10397) Flatten

```
Flatten[{list1, list2}, {2, 1}]
```

or [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58968/10397) `multiRiffle`

```
multiRiffle[x : _List ..] :=
 Module[{i = 1},
  Fold[Riffle[##, {++i, -1, i}] &, {x}]
 ]
multiRiffle[{list1, list2}]
```